# How do I find one String inside of another

Tags: java, string

When I search for a string in a string list, I will take a character that the string contains and return it as true. I need it to only take a whole string and only return true when it takes the whole string. Right now it does this: 
Input = a = true ,and,
Input= Tanner = true.
I need it to only do:
Input= Tanner = true

I have tried google alternatives to .contains, but I do not know the proper title to those statements.

```
`String userNames = "Tanner, Mr. Biggs, Xavier, Kaleb, James, Brady";
    for (int loginAttempts = 0; loginAttempts < 5; loginAttempts++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your username.");
        String userLogin = input.next();
        if (userNames.(userLogin)) {
            System.out.println("You are logged in.");
            break;`
```

It should only run the if statement if a full user name is entered not if a character in the username is entered. 
Eg. Input= Tanner = true
Input = a = false

Comment: Who and why did someone dislike my answer?

Comment: I would image it's because using the [String#contains()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) method is in no way accurate enough to test for **distinct** names or the proper name rather than part of a name. Place the contents of **userNames** into a string array using the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method. After the User enters his/her name then use a **for** loop to iterate over the array to see if there is equality between each array element and the supplied User Name.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give your names as a single String. Create a String array and then loop over the elements :

```
System.out.println("Please enter your username.");
        String userLogin = input.next();;
        String[] userNames = {"Tanner", "Mr. Biggs", "Xavier", "Kaleb", "James", "Brady"};
        for (int i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            if (userNames[i].equals(userLogin)) {
                System.out.println("You are logged in.");
                break;
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

`String.contains(String)`

It will search for a given sequence of characters inside of a String. For example,

```
String A = "ABCDEF";
System.out.println(A.contains("ABC")); // Prints true
```